# Fedora gives me a list of fedora installs at boot time

Tags: fedora, boot, virtualbox

The following happens when I start up Fedora, I've installed it on VirtualBox, how can I stop it from doing this? Both of them take me to same installation of Fedora, I have no clue on how this happened. How do I make it so it boots with just one of them?

The only difference is that the guest additions seemed to be installed on the first Fedora only.

[image]

The following are my VirtualBox settings for Fedora:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the topmost line.
It appeared after the `yum` updated your `kernel`.

The second line is for loading the previously installed kernel (in this case it is a kernel from distro)

The third line is self-describing.

If you do not touch keyboard it will load the default (the topmost in your case)

If you like to change the timeout value to speed it up - look at `man grub` and into the file `/boot/grub/grub.conf`